# Sed remove all text after and including the third underscore

Tags: regex, sed

I need to edit following string

> UA399_GTTTCG_L002_R1_001.file.gz

to

> UA399_GTTTCG_L002

I tried sed `'s/^\(.*\)_.*/\1/'` but that produces

> UA399_GTTTCG_L002_R1

Can someone help please?

Comment: What is the rule here? Delete all after the 3rd `_` including it?

Comment: I need to remove text after third underscore, including it.

Comment: Try just `awk -F'_' {'print $1"_"$2"_"$3'} <<< "$s"`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/Lrwlcx). It is possible with `sed`, too, but looks worse.

Comment: This guy `(.*\)` is greedy, try `([^_]+_[^_]+[^_]+\)` assuming your pattern X_X_X. Construction `[^_]` repaces your dot, basically. I think sed is justified when you need high performance of processing millions of log lines, otherwise use awk as suggested above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either `sed` or `awk` or `cut` like:

```
s='UA399_GTTTCG_L002_R1_001.file.gz'
awk -F'_' '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3}' <<< "$s"
sed 's/^\([^_]*\(_[^_]*\)\{2\}\).*/\1/' <<< "$s"
cut -d_ -f1,2,3 <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/UE2NVr). In both cases, the result is `UA399_GTTTCG_L002`.

***`sed` details***

- `^` - start of a line
- `\([^_]*\(_[^_]*\)\{2\}\)` - Capturing group 1 matching:

  - `[^_]*` - 0+ chars other than `_`
  - `\(_[^_]*\)\{2\}` - two consecutive occurrences (`\{2\}`) of:

    - `_` - an underscore
    - `[^_]*` -  0+ chars other than `_`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

The replacement is just the placeholder that contains the Group 1 text.

***`awk` details***

- `-F'_'` splits the record into underscore separated fields
- `print $1"_"$2"_"$3` prints only the first, second and third fields and concats them with `_` char.

***`cut` details***

- `-d_` sets the field delimiter to `_` char
- `-f1,2,3` selects only the specified set of fields (it may also accept a range of fields as in [Kent's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406831/3832970)).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `cut` for this problem:

```
cut -d'_' -f1-3 <<<STRING
```

With your example:

```
kent$  cut -d'_' -f1-3 <<<"UA399_GTTTCG_L002_R1_001.file.gz"
UA399_GTTTCG_L002
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/((_*[^_]*){3}).*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/_[^_]*//3g' file
```

Delete the third (or more) set(s) of characters beginning with an underscore and followed by zero or more non-underscores.